# How to calculate if age is in range from the birth year ,while fetching the birth year from Db in Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have a model which consists of id, name and birth year.I want to query this model  to get the name such that the age is in between a range.

For now, what i have tried is

```
queryset= Employees.objects.all()
```

For each name i calculate the age by:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
age=now.year-q.birth_year
ids=[]
if 25<age<36 :
   ids.append(q.id)
```

and then, 
   i query once again with ids
     Employees.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

Can i do all this in a single query.

```
Employees.objects.filter(**Calculate age and compare if it is in the range)
```

Range can be dynamic. I have the range in two variable minAge and maxAge.

Any help.

Comment: Dude, you put the `year` on `relativedelta` object, it should be `age_from = (today - relativedelta(years=25)).year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `relativedelta` from `dateutil`, it's more convenient to calculate the time:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = datetime.date.today()
age_25 = (today - relativedelta(years=25)).year
age_36 = (today - relativedelta(years=36)).year
Employees.objects.filter(birth_year__lte=age_25, birth_year__gte=36)
```

`age_25` is 25 years ago, `age_36` is 36 years ago, you just query the people's birthdays fall between 25 and 36 years ago.

For `lte` and `gte` check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gt) for details.

**Edit**:

Actually, django orm supports `range` query, so just do:

```
Employees.objects.filter(birth_year__range=[age_36, age_25])
```

Comment: Can you please explain how does it work. I will try this and see how this works.

Comment: I made some edit, you might need to have dateutil installed. `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: Thank you. This is something new to me. I will try and understand this.

Comment: It's not that hard to understand. In year 2016, 25 year old would be born in 1991, 36 year old would be born in 1980, you just query for birth year that falls between `[1980, 1991]`.

Comment: Yes, i Implemented this. Thank you so much.

Comment: ERROR: 'years' is an invalid keyword argument for this function .I have installed the package

Comment: Did you do `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta` then `relativedelta(years=25)`? Check the doc: https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454

Comment: TypeError :
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to babysit on this, but I just copied my code except the query and run in my shell and it works. Did you install the `dateutil` as I commented?